# ASP.Net Core MVC 6.0 Layout Issue

Tags: asp.net, layout

I am using ASP.Net Core MVC v6 and having an issue with the typical layout which is header, side menu bar, content and a footer. I have managed to get my side bar and content side by side using columns 2 and 10 but I footer is off the screen. I sort of know why but don't know how to fix it. I have searched on here and that is where I found the col solution but it does not help with the footer. I guess it has something to do with using  min-vh-100 but I don't know how to tell it to take into count the height of my footer. Any help please...